# Quel est le bon accord du verbe dans « l'une des meilleures choses qui me soit arrivée(s) » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, participe-passé, subordonnées

Comment devons-nous accorder le verbe dans cette phrase ?

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qui me soit arrivée.

ou

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qui me soient arrivées.

Logiquement, j'irais avec le premier choix, comme le sujet est *l'une*. Que pensez-vous ?

Answer (score 6):

Je mettrais plutôt le **pluriel**, qui est le choix le plus courant. Le sujet est "qui", et dans ce cas il se rapporte à "choses". La phrase signifie alors que plusieurs choses vous sont arrivées dans votre vie, et celle que vous citez est une des meilleures, à votre avis.

On pourrait éventuellement vouloir dire qu'une des meilleures choses (dans l'absolu) vous est arrivée à un moment donné. Dans ce cas j'utiliserais cependant l'indicatif et non le subjonctif (on est certain que c'est arrivé). Par ailleurs, l'usage d'une virgule avant le 'qui' permet de lever toute ambiguïté sur le sujet.

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses, qui m'est arrivée.

EDIT: Pour conclure, avec "la meilleure des ... que", les différentes combinaisons singulier/pluriel et indicatif/subjonctif sont grammaticalement acceptables. Cependant, si l'on regarde le sens de l'affirmation, la combinaison **pluriel/subjonctif** arrive en tête parce que "la meilleure" est un superlatif. Vient ensuite **pluriel/indicatif** si l'on souhaite renforcer l'idée qu'on tient compte de toute les choses qui nous sont arrivées (et qu'on n'a rien oublié). Enfin, **singulier/indicatif** implique un changement de sujet (comme pour "c'est l'un de mes meilleurs étudiants qui est tombé malade"): vous parlez d'une chose qui vous est arrivée, pas d'une chose parmi toutes celle qui vous sont arrivées. Spécifiquement pour votre phrase, je ne trouve pas de contexte capable de justifier la dernière combinaison.

Comment: Donc la tournure singulière est acceptable au présant mais non pas au subjonctif ?

Comment: le subjonctif ajoute une nuance de doute. en principe on sait si la chose en question nous est arrivée ou pas. Donc il est plus logique d'utiliser l'indicatif dans ce cas, mais le subjonctif reste grammaticalement correct. Il s'agit là de micro-nuances. La tournure singulière est déjà rare, mais ce n'est pas pour ça qu'elle est fausse.

Comment: Il y a deux aspects de la réponse : accord du verbe (personnellement je pense que l'accord au pluriel n'est pas seulement préférable mais s'impose); et choix du mode (subjonctif ou indicatif). S'agissant de choses qui se sont déjà réalisées, il n'y a pas lieu d'utiliser le subjonctif, mais le subjonctif dans ce genre de construction est un usage courant et acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

On ne peut pas dire « les meilleures choses qui <s>m'est</s> arrivée » alors que « les meilleures choses qui me sont arrivées » est correctement accordé.

Le pluriel est donc plus indiqué dans:

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qui me soient arrivées. (voir [ici](http://www.babelio.com/auteur/Helene-Gremillon/102722/citations/528966) par exemple)

ou tout simplement

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qui me sont arrivées (dans la vie).

Si l'on insiste pour le singulier, il faut une tournure impersonnelle que l'on rencontre aussi parfois (il m'est arrivé des choses), sans accord donc, :

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qu'il me soit arrivé.

voire

> C'est l'une des meilleures choses qu'il m'est arrivé.

mais elle m'écorche un peu l'oreille...

Comment: je ne dirais pas "c'est une des meilleure choses qui me soit arrivé". Pour la version impersonnelle j'utiliserais "c'est une des meilleures choses qu'il me soit arrivé".

Comment: @radouxju C'est vrai, merci !

Answer (score 1):

Clairement le pluriel, sans aucun doute possible pour moi. On est parfois surpris avec le français, mais il y a quand même souvent des raisons logiques aux bizarreries. Là, la phrase veut clairement dire "parmi toutes les choses qui me sont arrivées, c'est l'une des meilleures".